# $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$ implies $b^r =(b^m)^{1/n}$ is well-defined

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

In Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3e*, problem 6a on page 22, the following problem is stated:

> Fix $b>1$. If $m,n,p,q$ are integers, $n>0, q>0$, and $r=m/n=p/q$, prove that $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$.
>   Hence it makes sense to define $b^r=(b^m)^{1/n}$.

What puzzles me is how does proving that $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$ imply that $b^r=(b^m)^{1/n}$ is well-defined? I don't quite see the connection.

Comment: Representations of fractions are not unique, so in order for a definition involving fractions to be well-defined, you need to check that different representations of the same number give the same result.